# python socket unsetting an option without destroying the scoket

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I've a bunch of IPs and sending a UDP message to them.

```
for ip in transmit_ip:
    socket = socket.socket(socket.INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    if ip.endswith(".255"):
        socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST,1)
    socket.sendto(message, (ip, transmit_port))
    socket.close()
```

I wanted to create one socket and send to all the IPs through that socket. (Since UDP). Like this:

```
socket = socket.socket(socket.INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
for ip in transmit_ip:
    if ip.endswith(".255"):
        socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST,1)
    socket.sendto(message, (ip, transmit_port))
socket.close()
```

But the thing is, once a broadcast address comes, the `socket.SO_BROADCAST` option will be set to the socket.

In the first instance we are closing and recreating the socket for each IP, so it would not impact other IPs.

Is there a way to unset the socket options?

Comment: Why? All the option does is allow you to send broadcasts. It doesn't prevent you from sending unicasts. So there is no need to clear it. You could even set it before the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, like so:

```
socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 0)
```

(though I am not sure you actually need to do that in order to resume sending to non-broadcast addresses — I *think* `SO_BROADCAST` won't get in the way of that.)